# What we have in Play2 to modify request and response like filter in Servlet?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, servlet-filters

With Servlet API we can write filters to modify the request and response.If I use Play2 how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are possible ways to do that:

- Use filters http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaHttpFilters

This is very similar to Servlet filters. If you take a look at the examples provided in the docs you will get the idea.

- Using GlobalSettings (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaGlobal)

This allows you to hook into application start/stop events, specify error page or handle missing actions